# Input with default properties in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 project. I want to create for example datepicker with default properties. Because, there will be always same in my project. How can I achieve this?

My DatePicker (PrimeNg)

```
<p-calendar [locale]="tr" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
```

**But, I want like below**

```
<p-calendar {GeneralProperties} ></p-calendar>
```

**I know, I can make by new custom component.** But calendar has 40 property. So, I can't use any of them, if I write custom component like below. Forexample, in below, I can't give minDate propery.

```
<custom-calendar></custom-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. We can do by directives as @miladdn131 's said. We create a a directive which name is `calendar.directive.ts` . And then we import it in our `app.module.ts`. Then, calendar starts with default properties by in directives.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Directive({
  selector: 'p-calendar'
})

export class CalendarDirective {
  constructor(calendar: Calendar) {
    calendar.dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';
    calendar.autoZIndex = true;
    calendar.readonlyInput = true;
    calendar.showIcon = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom component, like your `custom-calendar` and redefine all properties like this:

```
@Input()
locale = "tr"
```

This will allow you to either use all defaults:

```
<custom-calendar></custom-calendar>
```

Or to specify any number of them manually:

```
<custom-calendar locale="de"></custom-calendar>
```

Comment: I can't do this. Because, there will be a lot of component like calendar, combobox, textarea, checbox..... And each of them has hundreds of properties. So, this is not possible in my situration. @slartidan

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use directive،directive are made for the same thing,
this link is good:
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives
https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-how-to-create-your-own-angular-directive-3532d7f31fab?gi=57835b58737
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_directives.htm

Comment: Thanks but can you explain please how can I do this with directive?Because I can't understand with that document. @Miladdn131

Comment: Thanks again @miladdn. But, I didn't understand the link you sent, the relationship with the question I asked. I read all post, and that post tells very different things from my question. I'm newbie in angular. Maybe, I can't understand.

Comment: in your p-calendar directive you can use :locale="tr",dateFormat="dd/mm/yy",can you give me your datePick.js? or controller code?var datePickerDirective = function () {

    var options = {
        calType: 'gregorian',
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm',
        multiple: true,
   
    };

Comment: `p-calendar` component is not mine. It is `PrimeNg's` component.https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar . So, there isn't any js file like datePick.js. I'm only pasting `<p-calendar [locale]="tr" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>` this code. And then working. But my question is independent from PrimeNg. It can be `<select>` element forexample. @miladdn131

Comment: you shold use this code for your export class MyModel {

    en: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.en = {
            firstDayOfWeek: 0,
            dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
             monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear'
        };
    }
}

Comment: I create `calendar-directive`. And I pasted your `MyModel` to directive (from in your last comment). How can I use this directive now? Forexample like `<p-calendar [MyModel] ></p-calendar>` ? @miladdn131

Comment: @miladdn131 Link-only answers are not preferred, here at stackoverflow. However your comments are valuable for Hasan and other users. Could you try to edit your answer, so that it contains the consensus of the comments?